# readkey command in python

Tags: python, readkey

I want my Python program to stop and wait until any key is pressed, then to print the key that was just pressed.

It's like the Pascal's command `key := readkey;  writeln(key);`.

I' ve tried yet to use the msvcrt module and the getch command but it didn' t work. I tried this:

```
import msvcrt 
s = msvcrt.getch()
print (s)
```

And it didn' t wait I pressed a key, it immediately printed `b'\xff'` and it ended the program

I' m working with python 3.4

Do you know any way to help me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: That work fine for me - although you might prefer to use: msvcrt.getche() to also echo the response back to the terminal. How are you running the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that if I started my .py file from the command line (pythonw) the command `msvcrt.getch()` didn' t work but if I save my .py file and I launched it, the command `msvcrt.getch()` worked correctly !

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure this will be usefull for anyone but the answer to this is

```
s = input()
```

This will store the input in the "s" variable.